# Consolidate all Excel tabs in workbook into minimum tabs on another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have 200 sheets in 1 workbook with an average of 65,000 records on each sheet. I am trying to build a macro that merges all sheets in 1 Excel file into the minimum number of sheets on a NEW Excel file. As Excel has a limitation of 1.xxx million records, the new file would have to have more than 1 sheet, but I am looking to consolidate as much as possible on the new file/tabs.

Below is what I have built so far, but I am struggling to even copy and past the data properly, let alone adding new sheets whenever needed.
Is anyone able to assist?

```
Sub Combine()
Dim J As Integer
Dim s As Worksheet


Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
Sheets(1).Select

'Opens initial file
strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
Workbooks.Open strFile
Set INITIALFILE = ActiveWorkbook


' copy headings
Sheets(1).Activate
Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Sheets(1).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).PasteSpecial

INITIALFILE.Activate
For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If s.Name <> "Combined" Then
        Application.GoTo Sheets(s.Name).[a1]
        Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
        ' Don't copy the headings
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
Selection.Copy
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Sheets(1).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
INITIALFILE.Activate
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Start by removing `On Error Resume Next`.  It will only hide the errors.

Comment: @DarrellH ohh I did that and I think I figured out the copy paste issue (Changed code above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `Range` object variables, you rarely need to use `Select` and your screen will be much the quieter. As noted using a general `On Error Resume Next` will make it almost impossible to make your code work properly as you will not see useful error messages.

```
Sub Combine()
Dim NewFile As Workbook
Dim InitialFile As Workbook
Const RowLimit As Long = 1000000

Dim strFile As String
Dim InRows As Long
Dim OutRows As Long
Dim FirstSheet As Worksheet
Dim OutSheet As Worksheet
Dim ASheet As Worksheet
Dim CopySet As Range
Dim OutLoc As Range
Dim Anon As Variant

Set NewFile = ActiveWorkbook
Set FirstSheet = NewFile.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
Set OutSheet = FirstSheet
Set OutLoc = OutSheet.Range("A1")

'Opens initial file
strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
Workbooks.Open strFile
Set InitialFile = ActiveWorkbook

OutSheet.Activate

For Each ASheet In InitialFile.Sheets
    Anon = DoEvents()
    If ASheet.Name <> "Combined" Then
        Set CopySet = ASheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
        If CopySet.Row + OutLoc.Row > RowLimit Then
            Set OutSheet = NewFile.Sheets.Add(After:=OutSheet)
            Set OutLoc = OutSheet.Range("A1")
        End If
        ' Only copy the headings if needed
        If OutLoc.Row = 1 Then
            Set CopySet = Range(ASheet.Range("A1"), CopySet)
        Else
            Set CopySet = Range(ASheet.Range("A2"), CopySet)
        End If
        CopySet.Copy OutLoc
        Set OutLoc = OutLoc.Offset(CopySet.Rows.Count, 0)
    End If
Next ASheet

FirstSheet.Activate

End Sub
```

The call to `DoEvents()` is there to keep the screen current rather than frozen in some half-drawn fashion.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! I was able to figure out the copy paste issue from above, but I was clueless on adding new sheets if over the limit!!!!